# Is there any advantage to restraining the angle passed to trigonometric functions?

Tags: javascript, math, optimization, trigonometry

I was wondering whether there was any advantage to clamping the angle passed to trigonometric functions between `0` and `Math.PI * 2`? I had a function which made heavy use of trigonometric functions, and someone in the project added this to the beggining:

```
angle %= Math.PI * 2;
```

Is there any advantage to this? Are the trigonometric functions faster if the angle passed is between those values? If so, shouldn't they clamp it themselves? Is there any other case where equivalent angles should be clamped?

The language is JavaScript, most likely to be run on V8 and SpiderMonkey.

Comment: The answer is going to be dependent on the platform you use.  What language / framework / compiler / etc are you using?  My suspicion is that it doesn't matter much in terms of perf, but it probably makes debugging a hell of a lot easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since most (on-die) algorithms for computing trigonometric functions use some variant of [CORDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC), my bet is that those values are getting clamped within [0, Pi/2) anyway at the entry point of the trig function call.

That being said, if you have a way to keep the angles close to zero throughout the algorithm, it is probably wise to do it. Indeed, the value of sin(10^42) is pretty much undefined, since the granularity in the 10^42 range is around 10^25.

This means for instance that if you are to add angles, and if by doing so, they can get large in magnitude, then you should consider periodically clamping them. But it is unneccessary to clamp them just before the trigonometric function call.

Comment: I fear your premise isn't necessarily true. I remember reading about this in the hotspot codebase where they had to remove optimizations for sin/cos computations because x86 CPUs (well the x87 coprocessor) don't use a high enough accuracy for PI or something. Edit: See [this](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4857011) here.

Comment: @Voo: Thanks for the link, it is indeed instructive. However, even if the article points out that on x86 the value of sin(pi) is strongly biased *in relative accuracy*, for most arguments this translate into practically machine precision, so I won't worry about the existing code which could be broken on x86 due to this. But indeed, the argument reduction is flawed on such machines. I'll test this on modern x86 computers.

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow your argument. If using a non reduced input argument, results in an output that is accurate to only 10billion ULPs or so (stolen from the thread) instead of the expected 1/2 or 1 than this seems problematic. I mean generally I'd expect the "same" output for `sin(2PI * 1000000000 + 1)` and `Sin(1)` - well not necessarily exactly the same, but still somewhere in the same range. Though the question is how important x87 is today - is there some SSE intrinsic?

Comment: @Voo: "10 billion ULP" is only for sin(pi) (and this makes absolute accuracy of 10^-15 IIRC). For other numbers, absolulte accuracy is OK. You can't represent pi correctly in floating point arithmetic anyway.

Answer (score 0):

An advantage of clamping angles to the range -pi/4 to pi/4 (use sine or cosine as appropriate) is that you can ensure that if the angles are computed using some approximation of pi, range reduction is performed using *that same approximation*.  Such an approach will have two benefits: it will improve the accuracy of things like the sine of 180 degrees or the cosine of 90 degrees, and it will avoid having math libraries waste computational cycles in an effort to perform super-accurate range reduction by a "more precise" approximation of pi which doesn't match the one used in computing the angles.

Consider, for example, the sine of 2⁴⁸ * pi.  The best `double` approximation of pi, times 2^48, is 884279719003555, which happens to also be the best double approximation of 2⁴⁸π.  The actual value of 2⁴⁸π is 884279719003555.03447074.  Mod-reducing the best double approximation the former value by the best double approximation of pi would yield zero, the sine of which equals the correct sine of 2⁴⁸π.  Mod-reducing by π the value scaled up by the best approximation of pi will yield -0.03447074, the sine of which is -0.03446278.